# How to choose in which QLineEdit should my text put in

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qlineedit

I'm working on a project where i have some qpushbuttons and some QlineEdit using qt c++. I want to choose in which QLineEdit my text should be appear. As far I put some text only in the first QLineEdit and the other is filled by condition depending on the first

Comment: So what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: the text i want to put in is trough qpushbuttons only, and no keyboard. So I want every time to push a button to know if I can choose in which Qlineedit my text will be in.

Comment: Create a click listener and when the button is clicked, you choose the ID of QLineEdit however you want and fill it with text.

Answer (score 0):

[QInputDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qinputdialog.html) is a way to get user input.

And I think you need [QInputDialog::getItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qinputdialog.html#getItem) to choice one of many things.